# Java automatic click w/coordinate

Tags: java

I'm working in the [Dr. java](http://www.drjava.org/) environment, and I need a function that receives a coordinate (i.e `(200,300)`) and clicks it on the screen - I could implement one, but I'm pretty sure there has to be something already implemented in the language. For some reason I can't find one (I've looked in many different places), and I'll appreciate it if I wont need to link any external libraries. Thanks in advance (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the Java Robot class (here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) It includes a mouseMove method that does exactly what you want.

```
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.InputEvent;

public class MainClass {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

    Robot r = new Robot();
    r.mouseMove(35,35);
    r.mousePress( InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK );
    r.mouseRelease( InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK );
    Thread.sleep(50);
    r.mousePress( InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK );
    r.mouseRelease( InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK );
  }
}
```

Source: http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/java.awt/RobotmouseMoveintxinty.htm